# parse signed transaction error

Tags: cardano-serialization-lib

I am using the cardano-serialization-lib to derive addresses and create a transaction unsigned.. See below

const signed_transaction = await cardanolib.Transaction.new(
newTx.body(),
witnesses,
undefined //metadata
);

Then I submit the signed transaction to the blockchain using the rosetta-api's /construction/submit endpoint， return failed：

{
"code": 5003,
"message": "Parse signed transaction error",
"retriable": false
}

What kind of encoding is required to submit a transaction signed with serialization lib with rosetta-api?